# Learning to Use Virtual Manager in opensuse 12.2

Tags: opensuse, kvm, virt-manager

Ok just installed virt-manager, and then install opensuse 12.2, installed correctly, but when do zypper up had no network, then turn off the virtual machine and change the network card to a vlan in the configuation files. Another thing I did as I was was to rename the vm.

When I reboot I got the following error:

[image]

Comment: No need to close that question. The question is: What is going on here. So someone using KVM on OpenSuSE should be able to answer this. Perhaps that "change to vlan" could be described in more detail...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have the permissions to access the socket for communication with the libvirt daemon. The [openSUSE documentation about libvirt](http://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/html/openSUSE/opensuse-kvm/cha.libvirt.connect.html) explains how to get non-root access. To solve your specific problem it should be enough to run virt-manager with sudo, i.e. `sudo virt-manager`

Comment: actually I run virt-manager as root, but the link is very useful thanks!